# Is it possible to solve this equation using lambert function

Tags: transcendental-equations, lambert-w

Can the following equation be solved using Lambert function?

$$x(1+e^x)=a$$

Answer (score 2):

No. [Lambert's W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)  solves only cases of the form $~xe^x=$ constant, whereas here we have $xe^x=$ variable.

Comment: Often other equations can be manipulated into the form we need.  But apparently not here.

Answer (score 2):

We know that mixed exponential/bilinear equations can be solved by the extended Lambert function $W_r(x)$, which can be represented by the following Lagrange inverting series:

$$z(A,t,s)=t- (t-s) \sum_{n=1} \frac{L_n' (n(t-s))}{n} e^{-nt} A^n$$

which is the solution of:

$$e^z=A\frac{z-t}{z-s}$$

**Related questions**

Related question concerning equations of the form:
$$e^z=A\frac{z-t}{z-s}$$

[Lambert W function with rational polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033398/lambert-w-function-with-rational-polynomial)

[Solve $-B \ln y -A y \ln y + A y- A =0$ for $y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353156/solve-b-ln-y-a-y-ln-y-a-y-)

[Transcendental equations involving more than 2 terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194045/transcendental-equations-involving-more-than-2-terms?lq=1)

[How to solve this equation for x? $0 = (x+k)e^{-(x+k)^2}+(x-k)e^{-(x-k)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219635/how-to-solve-this-equation-for-x-0-xke-xk2x-ke-x-k2/1221474#1221474)

[Solving equation involving self-exponentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064929/solving-equation-involving-self-exponentiation/1251230#1251230)

**References**

On the generalization of the Lambert $W$ function with applications in theoretical physics, http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999

[68] C. E. Siewert and E. E. Burniston, "Solutions of the Equation $ze^z=a(z+b)$," Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, 46 (1974) 329-337. http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ces/pdfversions/68.pdf

Answer (score 2):

$\def\M{\operatorname M}$
Instead of Lagrange inversion, let’s apply [Mellin inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem):

$$f(x)=x(e^x+1)\implies f^{-1}(x)=h(x)=\M^{-1}_x(\M_s(h(t))\\\M_s(h(t))=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}h(t)dt=\int_0^\infty t f(t)^{s-1}df(t)$$

Next, use integration by parts and the [$(z+1)^a$ Mellin Barnes integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+representation+%28z%2B1%29%5Ea) to get

$$\M_s(h(t))=\frac1s\int_0^\infty (t(e^t+1))^sdt=-\frac i{2\pi s \Gamma(-s)}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \Gamma(-s-w)\Gamma(w)\int_0^\infty t^se^{-wx}dtdw$$

The $t$ integral is a gamma function and the resulting $s$ inverse Mellin transform integral gives [confluent hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/). Therefore:

$$\bbox[4px,border:3px solid #1ae]{f(x)=x(e^x+1)\implies f^{-1}(x)=-\frac 1{4\pi^2}\int_{c_1-i\infty}^{c_1+i\infty}\int_{c_2-i\infty}^{c_2+i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(-s-w)\Gamma(w)s!}{x^sw^{s+1}(-s)!} dsdw=-\frac{ix}2\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\csc(\pi t)\,_1\text F_1(1-t;2;-tx)dt=\frac x{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{it}\ln\left(e^{xe^{it}}(e^{-i t}+1)+1\right)dt}$$

where approximately $0<c_1,-c_2<1$. Also, [converting](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/27/01/0001/) the $_1\text F_1$ function into a Laguerre $\operatorname L_{t-1}^1(w)$ function and using its [integral representation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-LaguerreL%284.2-1%2C1%2C3.4%29%2CNintegrate%5B-%28e%5E%28i+r+-+e%5E%28i+r%29+3.4%29+%281+%2B+e%5E%28-i+r%29%29%5E4.2%29%2F%282+%CF%80%29%2C%7Br%2C0%2C2%CF%80%7D%5D) gives the final result.

All verified here:

[image]