# How to solve equation $(ax+b)\exp(x) = (cx+d)$ using Lambert W function

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w

Are there any closed form solutions to

$$(ax+b)\exp(x)= cx+d$$

for real-valued $a,b,c$ and $d$?

Comment: The solution is by the function you mentioned: Lambert $W\,.$

Comment: I do not see a solution of this with Lambert W.  However, you can solve $(ax+b)\exp(x) = d$ with Lambert W.  You can also solve $b\exp(x) = cx+d$.

Comment: @GEdgar. It is the generalized Lambert function

Comment: @njuffa. Done. Nice but not very practical (from my point of view). Cheers

Comment: Aside from the series representation in the Arxiv paper, there is a way to get a Mellin Barnes type solution and a real integral representation like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801109/is-it-possible-to-solve-this-equation-using-lambert-function/4746643#4746643)

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the equation as
$$e^{-x}=\frac{a x+b}{c x+d}=\frac a c\,\frac{x+\frac b a}{x+\frac d c}$$

The solution is given in terms  of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$ in the paper).

Comment: István Mező and Árpád Baricz, "On the generalization of the Lambert $W$ function." *Transactions of the American Mathematical Society,* Vol. 369, No. 11, Nov. 2017, pp. 7917-7934 ([online](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2017-369-11/S0002-9947-2017-06911-7/S0002-9947-2017-06911-7.pdf))

Comment: @njuffa. There are many papers around this topic.