# Solving equation involving self-exponentiation

Tags: transcendental-equations, lambert-w

How do I solve the equation $\displaystyle x=ay^2(by)^{\frac 1y}$ for $y$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants? I've been trying to manipulate this into a form on which I can use the Lambert W function, but I don't know whether this is possible or if so how to do it.

Sorry about the title, I couldn't think of anything more accurate without putting the entire equation in the title and I didn't want to just say "solving equation" or some such.

Comment: Trying the sub $$by = \frac{1}{v}$$ we can obtain
$$
u^2 (u^u)^{-b}  = u^{2-bu}= \frac{a}{b^2}\frac{1}{x}
$$ Maybe this can help..atm I can not see it ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the logarithm of:
 $\displaystyle x=ay^2(by)^{\frac 1y}$
we obtain:
$$\log(x)=\log(a)+2\log(y)+{\log(by) \over y}$$
placing $z=\log(by)$:
$$\log(x)=\log(a)+2z+({\log(b)+z})e^{-z}$$
$$e^{-z}={\log(x/a)-2z \over {\log(b)+z}}$$
or:
$$e^{z}=\frac{\log(b)+z }{\log(x/a)-2z }$$
We know that mixed exponential/bilinear equations can be solved by the extended Lambert function $W_r(x)$, which can be represented by the following Lagrange inverting series:

$$z(A,t,s)=t- (t-s) \sum_{n=1} \frac{L_n' (n(t-s))}{n} e^{-nt} A^n$$

which is the solution of:

$$e^z=A\frac{z-t}{z-s}$$

**Related questions**

Related question concerning equations of the form:
$$e^z=A\frac{z-t}{z-s}$$

[Lambert W function with rational polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033398/lambert-w-function-with-rational-polynomial)

[Solve $-B \ln y -A y \ln y + A y- A =0$ for $y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353156/solve-b-ln-y-a-y-ln-y-a-y-)

[Transcendental equations involving more than 2 terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194045/transcendental-equations-involving-more-than-2-terms?lq=1)

[How to solve this equation for x? $0 = (x+k)e^{-(x+k)^2}+(x-k)e^{-(x-k)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219635/how-to-solve-this-equation-for-x-0-xke-xk2x-ke-x-k2/1221474#1221474)

**References**

On the generalization of the Lambert $W$ function with applications in theoretical physics, http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999

[68] C. E. Siewert and E. E. Burniston, "Solutions of the Equation $ze^z=a(z+b)$," Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, 46 (1974) 329-337. http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ces/pdfversions/68.pdf

Comment: I don’t follow your first substitution.  From the equation $\log x= \log a +2\log y + \frac{\log(by)}{y}$, substituting $z=\log (by)$ and solving for $y$ in terms of $z$ I got $y=\frac{10^z}{b}$.  Plugging into the original equation, I got $\log x = \log a + 2 \log y + \frac zy$ and then $\log x = \log a + 2(z- \log b) + \frac zy$ and then $\log x = \log a + 2z - 2\log b + bz10^{-z}$ and then $10^{-z}= \frac{\log(\frac xa)-2z+2\log b}{bz}$.  Also, I notice that your equations use “log” but you introduced base e.  Isn’t that incorrect?  A log with an unspecified base has base 10. Ln has base e.